# Font-Awesome icon preventing click in parent button

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm having a problem where the **left two pixels** of a Font-Awesome icon I've placed inside of a button element do not trigger the click event of the button.

Here's an example button:

```
<button class="btn btn-mini">
    <i class="icon-edit"></i>
</button>
```

And here's what it looks like with bootstrap

[image: Styled bootstrap button with Font-Awesome icon within]

Any ideas for why those left two pixels don't trigger a click event?

**Edit**: Here's a test site where I've managed to recreate the issue: http://ace.cwserve.com

Comment: Can u post an example on jsfiddle.net illustrating the issue?

Comment: Darnit. I can't, it seems more to do with the framework I'm using. I'll try to post an example site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this post is 4 years old but it might help people understand why a font-awesome "icon" inside a button prevents the click event.

When rendered, the icon class adds a **::before** pseudo-element to the icon tag that prevents the button's click event.

[image: rendered icon]

Given this situation, we should definitly take a look at the [CSS pointer-events Property](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_pointer-events.asp)

> The pointer-events property defines whether or not an element reacts
> to pointer events.

So we just need to add this css declaration for the "icon" which is inside a button:

```
button > i {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Outline

The [`outline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#dynamic-outlines) isn't part of the CSS box, which means it won't fire click events. This is perhaps slightly counter-intuitive, but that's how it works ...

Your page sets an outline on `.btn:focus`, but this doesn't seem to be the problem, since it has an offset of -2 (meaning it's displayed inside the box, rather than outside of it).

#### Moving the box on :active

You can move the box on `:active`, which can cause neat effect, but first the box is moved, and *then* will the click event be fired, which will *use the moved position*.
You can see this in action by keeping the mouse button pressed; the box will move, but the event won't be fired until you release the button. So if you move your box to the right by then pixels, then the left 10 pixels won't do anything.
This is according to spec, from the [DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html):

> **click**
>   The click event occurs when the pointing device button is clicked over an element. A click is defined as a mousedown and mouseup
>   over the same screen location. The sequence of these events is:
>
> - mousedown
> - mouseup
> - click

This seems to be the problem, this following CSS seems to solve it:

```
button.btn:active { 
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
}
```

#### Example

Here's a script to demonstrate both issues:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><style>
    body { margin-left: 30px; }
    div {
        background-color: red;
        border: 20px solid green;
        outline: 20px solid blue;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
    }

    div:active {
        left: 20px;
        top: 20px;
    }
</style></head> <body>
<div></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('div').on('click', function(e) {
        alert('click!');
    });
</script></body></html>
```

Comment: Looking at the CSS inspector, neither the icon or the button show an outline property. (Good to know though)

Comment: @cswilby It's seems to be on the `.btn:focus` :-) I've updated my answer.

Comment: Just gave that a try in Chrome and no luck I'm afraid, when I zoom all the way in on the button and click within the left line of the edit icon - the click event still isn't fired :(

Comment: @Cameron Wilby you're right, I'm sorry. I must've miss-clicked, it's a really small area and I've met 3 year olds with better motor skills. I've updated my answer *again*, making very sure I didn't miss-click... I sure hope I got it right this time ...

Comment: The issue persists through it all! This is a sneaky one.

Comment: @Cameron Wilby Not wanting to sound condescending, but are you sure? I examined this carefully with Opera (12) & Firefox, and just double-checked it, and it definitely solves the problem for me. I'm unable to figure out how to properly use Chrome's dev tools to disable the `:active` styling (it keeps getting re-enabled). It's possible that there's some `-webkit` CSS being applied, or something, but I don't see any ... Try commenting the CSS out on the server, to be sure ...

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but Font Awesome has added the ability to use SVG format for its icons, so selecting the `<i>` element using CSS is no longer an option if you have enabled SVG in your FA Kit settings, you can inspect the  yourself using your browser's dev tools, you'll see it is now wrapped in HTML comments! unless you turn on "**Enable Compatibility with Older Versions**" in your FA Kit settings. If enabling the compatibility with older FA versions is not an option or you just want to use the latest method, you can use the following instead in your CSS file:

```
[data-prefix='fas'] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

But if you do find yourself switching between the old and newer methods you can just use:

```
button > i, [data-prefix='fas'] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Now clicking on the `<button>` element with either of the above solutions while using FA should now continue working again as you intended.