# Click event on button is sending an icon as the target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I am having an issue very similar to: ["Jquery 'click' not firing when icon is on button"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085257/jquery-click-not-firing-when-icon-is-on-button) however the resolution for that post is not providing a solution for me, so I think something different may be going on.

The essential problem is that I have a button with an icon in it. When I click on the button (e.g. the text) the event target is the button element; however when I click on the icon, the event target is the icon object. This unfortunately is extremely annoying as I am storing data values on my button that I would like access to.

Here is the HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-success vote-button" id="btnUpVote" type="button" data-vote="1">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
    Up Vote!
</button>

<button class="btn btn-danger vote-button" id="btnDownVote" type="button" data-vote="-1">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>
    Down Vote!
</button>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
function sendVote(event) {
    var $btn = $(event.target);
    console.log(parseInt($btn.data('vote'));
    console.log($btn.prop('tagName'));
}

$('body').on('click', 'button.vote-button', sendVote);
```

Clicking on the text ("Up Vote!" or "Down Vote!") results in the following console output:

```
1
BUTTON
-1 
BUTTON
```

Clicking on the icon (, etc.) results in the following console output:

```
NaN
I
NaN
I
```

Even though I've registered the handle on elements with selector "button.vote-button". Does anyone know why this is happening? I'd hate to have to give data attributes to the icons.

Comment: instead of `console.log(parseInt($btn.data('vote'));` try     `console.log(parseInt($btn.attr('data-vote'));` For some reason I get this issue sometimes too..

Comment: Well, I did try it- but the same problem occurs. The issue isn't accessing the data table, but that the wrong element is the target of the click event.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's caused by event propagation. You click on the icon, which is inside the button, so the `click` event propagates up through the DOM from the icon, to the button, all the way up to the document. This results in your `click` event handler code being executed.

If the issue is that you just want the reference to the button every time that code runs, but you still want it to trigger when you click on the icon instead of the text, you just need to use `this` rather than `event.target`:

```
var $btn = $(this);
...
```

jQuery will make sure that `this` always refers to the button, even if the actual `event.target` element is an element inside it.

Comment: Hmm - ok; that must have to do more with the jQuery binding rather than the event itself. It definitely works, even if it's more worrisome! Thanks.

Comment: this works in jQuery only. For a universal solutions, use @Han implementation (commented below)

Comment: @mayid if you use `this` in callback you should bet the correct object whether or not you jQuery.

Answer (score 105):

Use `event.currentTarget` which is always the object listening for the event; `event.target` is the actual target that received the event which is not what you want in this case since it could be the icon.

With `event.currentTarget` if the user clicks on the icon, it'll bubble the event up to the object listener which is the button in your case. If the user clicks the button it'll still work because again the object listener is your button.

Comment: this works like magic! thanks so much! I was having the issue in react

Comment: this saved me!!

Comment: Thanks for the response! This saved me

Answer (score 15):

Simple CSS solution:

```
button > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple :) Helped me a lot when I struggled with event delegation. Thanks!

Comment: Easy!   This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

update this because `$(event.target)` is not always `button` for this you have to use ternary operator as suggested or replace `$(event.target)` with `$(this)` which is always `button` in the context of selector:

```
function sendVote(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    var $btn = $(event.target).is('button') ? $(event.target) : $(event.target).parent();
    console.log(parseInt($btn.data('vote')));
    console.log($btn.prop('tagName'));
}
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click','button.vote-button', sendVote);
});
```

---

#### [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z74CG/)

---

or with `$(this)` which is always `button` because the event is bound to it and if you click on any child of it then `event` will bubble up to the dom tree and event bound to button gets executed:

```
function sendVote(event) {
    var $btn = $(this);  // <-----------------change just here
    console.log(parseInt($btn.data('vote')));
    console.log($btn.prop('tagName'));
}
```

Comment: I'm basically doing something similar already. A quick note: for Chrome at least, the tagName is 'BUTTON' not 'button' which makes this solution seem a bit fragile on different browsers. (If I mess up the logic I get the `div` when I click on the button). And anyway, this isn't really what I'm looking for- I want to know how to bind to the button alone, not any inner html.

Comment: @bbengfort you can see the updates and see the fiddle link if that helps.

Comment: Well, that's certainly a better solution then testing the tagName; if no one comes up with anything better, I'll accept this solution- but I'd really like to find an answer with the binding - or possibly its in the CSS? See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653978/font-awesome-icon-preventing-click-in-parent-button?rq=1

Comment: for this in the function `$(event.target)` should be changed with `$(this)` then.

Comment: Whoops - yeh, that seems like the solution; but Anthony got there first. Thanks for the discussion though!

Answer (score 0):

How bout just checking within the function if the tagname is I, and if it is, getting the parent as your $btn.
http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/qZgYU/3/

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.vote-button', function() {
 var $btn = $(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase() == "i" ? $(this).parent() : $(this);
 console.log(parseInt($btn.data('vote')));
 console.log($btn.prop('tagName'));
});
```

Comment: See my answer to @Jai above- testing the tagName is fragile because in Chrome at least the tagname is all caps ("I" instead of "i"). Therefore when I go to the jsfiddle in Chrome, this code snippet doesn't work.

Comment: @bbengfort alright then, how about this (added `.toLowerCase()`)? and the fiddle works fine in my chrome.. :/